# PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR, sql, node.js

Tags: node.js

учусь подключаться к БД SQL с помощью node.js, но страничка выдает {"code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR","fatal":false}

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const app = express();

const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM public.products";

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "12345",
  database: "react_sql",
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  }
});

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
        data: results,
      });
    }
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Products server listening on port 4000");
});
```

Базу данных создал в postgreSQL

[image: Моя база данных]

Comment: используемая бд - postresql, а используемый драйвер require("mysql"). что-то тут не сходится. надо или https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg или https://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: блин, логично, пойду устанавливать mysql, спасибо)

Comment: и, кстати, я не эксперт в использовании mysql, но вижу, что обычно используют npm-пакет mysql2